# Running external process from Qt program, with some changes

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have 2 programs:

program 1 - A Qt program written by me.

program 2 - A program not written by.

My goal is to run program 2 from program 1 ( I know how to do that).

My problem, however, is that program 2 has some .ini files which it looks for. It turns out that the directory program 2 looks in is not the directory of the executable, but rather the directory of the process *starting* the executable...in this case program 1.

so my error reads something like this:

"could not find file xxx.ini in directory C://directory of program 1//inifiles//...

my question is...is there any way I can go around this? I know it's a little confusing, so please tell me if something doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `QProcess` to start program 2, you need to set the working directory by calling `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory(const QString &dir)`.

The [documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory) states:

> Sets the working directory to dir. QProcess will start the process in
>   this directory. The default behavior is to start the process in the
>   working directory of the calling process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out what directory you're currently using try something like:

```
QDir application_dir = QDir( QDir::currentPath() );
```

This is quite useful for debugging purposes.